# Sending a json object over Flash Builder 4 webservices

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, actionscript-3, json, flash-builder

Can I use the webservice wizards in Flash Builder 4 to **send** a json encoded object...not as a string but as type application/json; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Solution I've used is to simply use the WSDL services to map data instead. Not really a solution to using JSON, but more an over arching solution that my apply to your project.